# Enable user sign up in Omnibus GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I have installed gitlab-omnibus on ubuntu server following the instructions.
It works fine but now I'd like to allow users to sign up.

Every result mentions editing the gitlab.yml file, the problem is that I don't have that file at all, I only have gitlab.rb

I tried to add:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_signup_enabled'] = true
```

but that didn't work at all even after running a reconfigure and restarting gitlab

In the admin dashboard I see listed it among the disabled features no matter what I do.

How do I enable it in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce what you see.

Actions:

- add `gitlab_rails['gitlab_signup_enabled'] = true` to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
- run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Outcome:

- signup is enabled
- `sudo grep signup /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml` says `signup_enabled: true`.

  I found this file by looking at the output of `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, or with `locate`.

  What does it say for you? Does it work if you edit and change to `signup_enabled: true` and run `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`?

Comment: I located the file, in it signup_enabled is set to true already. After following all the instructions if I browse to the gitlab address I still get the sign in page with no sign up option.

Also the sign up feature still shows up as "off" in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ciro:
In the newer version the setting could be done at the admin application settings:
admin/application_settings

**Sign-in Restrictions**
Sign-up enabled

That may be the reason that it does not show the does not work for you. gitlab_rails['gitlab_signup_enabled'] = true

Comment: Yes, the config file setting doesn't work since GitLab 7.9.0.
For anyone who gets here and may be looking for more info see
[Gitlab Issue 2873](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2837)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and finally solved by changing underlying database directly:

```sh
sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-psql -c '\x' -c 'update application_settings set signup_enabled=true;'
```